# Java program does not run and throws an error about classes

Tags: java

So I want to run my just compiled Start.class file that I compiled from Start.java. The problem is that it will throw this error:

```
java Start 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Start (wrong name: files/Start)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I have written the program in Eclipse and I want to run it from a Terminal. What is the problem here?

New error:

```
java files.Start http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.53/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.53.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
    at files.Start.main(Start.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: How are you running it exactly?

Comment: Dunno. Where's your code?

Comment: There's no `Start` class in your environment, and it is needed for the execution.

Comment: @Kon I run it by typing java Start.  AntonH, I cannot share the code sadly.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, will see to it.

Comment: Is this `Start` class inside a package?

Comment: It sounds like you should use `java files.Start` from a parent directory.

Comment: This start class is in the Start.java that I just compiled into Start.class

Comment: @Veske: Given the "files/Start" part of the error message though, it sounds like it's in a package called `files`. The class name you pass to the `java` binary is a *fully-qualified* class name.

Comment: Could you post the class header for the relevant class, at least?

Comment: I edited my question, using @Jon Skeet's answer, I got a new error.

Comment: you have to set the class path where all the dependencies are placed.

Comment: Are you able to run other Java programs from Terminal? Does a simple Hello World program run?

Comment: @Braj how is that done?

Comment: You should review a tutorial related to how to execute Java applications using command line tools.

Comment: Now you have a problem seeing the library. I would suggest just getting on google and see what you can figure out yourself and then come back to stacked overflow to ask questions are what you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [How to Compile and Run Java Code from a Command Line](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/) where you will get the information about the class path and how to add dependent jars in class path.

---

Here is the details from above link.

**Task**

Lets say we have a fairly standard java project that consists of three top level folders:

> **/bin** - empty folder that will contain compiled .class files
>
> **/lib** - contains third party .jar files
>
> **/src** - contains .java source files`

Our task would be to compile and launch the project from its root folder. We will use Windows OS as example (on Unix systems the only difference would be path separation symbol - ":" instead of ";").

**Compiling Java Code**

The first step is compiling plain text .java sources into Java Virtual Machine byte code (.class files). This is done with javac utility that comes with JDK.

Assuming we are at the application root folder trying to compile Application.java file from com.example package that uses lib1.jar and lib2.jar libraries from lib folder to a destination bin folder, compilation command should have the following format:

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar src/com/example/Application.java
```